# python requests gets error 61 connection refused but postman worked with same GET request

Tags: python, python-requests, postman

Before I posted this, I have spend 2 hrs to googled a solution, but none worked, so finially im here

I tried to use `requests` and `urllib.request` and put in the `user-agent` header but still get `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused`

However it worked in postman

the url I am trying to get the html page content is `https://fangj.github.io/friends/season/0101.html`

why isn't this code working?

```
import sys
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()

headers = {
    'user-agent' : ua.chrome
}

url = 'https://fangj.github.io/friends/season/0101.html'

res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(res.content)
```

error as follow

```
/usr/bin/python3 "/Users/Dave/Desktop/SAT Preprocess/crawler.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 170, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 706, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 353, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 182, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x103cb8b38>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Dave/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 756, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 573, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='fangj.github.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /friends/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x103cb8b38>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Dave/Desktop/SAT Preprocess/crawler.py", line 20, in <module>
    res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  File "/Users/Dave/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Dave/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Dave/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/Dave/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Dave/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='fangj.github.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /friends/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x103cb8b38>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

Comment: Your script works for me, but the page is not found. Are you behind a firewall or a proxy?

Comment: your url is wrong in the script the correct one is https://fangj.github.io/friends/season/0101.html

Comment: @BendikKnapstad Thanks for pointing out the url is wrong but thats not the problem(same error)

Comment: are you behind a firewall or a proxy?

Comment: @BendikKnapstad not sure if thats the case, i did not alter anything with my internet and it works for requesting other pages. Its just this page i cant get access to

Comment: oh i see, have you run your script a lot? you might have been cut off for fetching the same endpoint a lot

Comment: @BendikKnapstad I got this error on the first trial and ever since, it is true that you could get 61 after requesting one endpoint too much, but it is so unfortunate that this is not the case. it would be much easier if so

Comment: I see, if you're not behind a proxy or firewall I'm afraid I have no other help to offer.
I can get the url without even setting a useragent.

Comment: @BendikKnapstad I appreciate your response, now I tried it on an online compiler and it worked, i guessed its just my laptop is fighting against me

Comment: the error i am getting is for fake_user agent not for the actual request

Comment: @PDHide I get error using or not using fake agent, as for your error, you might want to check out its documentation https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/

Answer (score 0):

Removing the s from https worked for me

Comment: Generally speaking, that's not a good idea. HTTPS connections are much more secure than HTTP ones, and are quickly becoming the default thanks to services like Let's Encrypt that make certificate generation trivial and free.